# Mask a text field in Jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, decimal

I would like to remove the zeros in my variable, I have used the properties section in my jasper studio but to no success. My variable is the following: `"("+$V{var_low_perc}+"%)"`. It gives me a result of 9.0 and all I want it to do is to give me a 9. I have put a post before regarding trailing zeros but am using groovy language.This is the mask I tried out in the properties field `#,##0;` but it gave me nothing is there a way i can add this in my source?

Answer (score 0):

Integer.valueOf(${var_low_perc})